# vimgrep pattern and immediately open quickfix in split mode

Tags: vim

Not sure if this has been ask, if so I can't find it.

I want to run vimgrep to search for a pattern. I've been doing this. And when it find a match, it seems to open up the first file right away.

This is not what I want. I want the quickfix window to be open in horizontal pane split for me to navigate through the matches. This is my command in `vimrc`

`command! -nargs=1 Ngrep vimgrep "<args>" **/*.md`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this snippet to your `vimrc` to tell Vim to automatically open the location/quickfix window after `:make`, `:grep`, `:lvimgrep` and friends if there are valid locations/errors:

```
augroup myvimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l*    lwindow
augroup END
```

If you don't want Vim to jump to the first match, use the `j` flag:

```
:vimgrep /foo/j **/*.md
```

as explained in `:help :vimgrep`.