# Quickfix windows doesn't open

Tags: vim

I am running vanilla Vim without any plugin or anything in my vimrc however the quickfix windows doesn't open when I run `:grep foo %`

I am following the tutorial here:
https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/demystifying_multi_file_searches_in_vim_and_the_command_line

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May 11 2018 15:17:01)

Is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 2):

`:grep` only runs an external grep command defined in `grepprg` (have a look at yours with `:set grepprg?`). So yes, it does not change the state of the quickfix window per default.

However you could write your own grep command:

```
command! -nargs=+ NewGrep execute 'silent grep! <args>' | copen
```

Or you could use an Autocommand, to trigger the `copen` after a grep. Have a look here: [vimgrep pattern and immediately open quickfix in split mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009792/vimgrep-pattern-and-immediately-open-quickfix-in-split-mode)

Comment: Thank you. Using Fugitive, the default behavior is to not open the quick fix windows as well. https://vimawesome.com/plugin/fugitive-vim

Comment: For Ggrep, to add: ```autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow```